# clickable links in plainTeX document

Tags: pdf, tex, pdftex

Is it possible to define clickable links in a plainTeX document when compiled with pdftex?
As far as I can see there is no support in plainTeX for this feature.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314041/hyperlinks-in-plain-tex

Comment: Can you clarify if you are using plain tex or latex? Your title and tags says one thing, the text of your question another....

Comment: right, I'll update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating clickable links in pdf documents generated from a `TeX` (`plainTex`) document you can use this code:

```
\newif\ifpdfmode
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
\else
    \ifnum\pdfoutput>0 \pdfmodetrue\fi
\fi

\def\url#1{%
    % turn off the special meaning of ~ inside \url{}.
    \begingroup\catcode`\~=12\catcode`\_=12\relax
    \ifpdfmode
        \pdfstartlink user{
            /Subtype /Link
            % w/o this you get an ugly box around the URL.
            /Border [ 0 0 0 ]   % radius, radius, line thickness
            /A <<
                /Type /Action
                /S /URI
                /URI (https://#1)
        >>
        }%
        {\tt#1}%
        \pdfendlink{}%
    \else
        %{\tt https\negthinspace:\negthinspace/\negthinspace/#1}%
        {\tt#1}%
    \fi
    \endgroup}
```

that you can save in a file named `lib/url.sty`.
Note that it injects some pdf code because links are not natively supported by TeX (even when using the `pdftex` compiler).

Once done it's just a question of using the macro `url` in your `TeX` code:

```
\input lib/url.sty

My preferred site is \url{stackoverflow.com}!
```

The macro `\url` works also when the document is not compiled with `pdftex`. In this case the conditional `ifpdfmode` will be set to `false` by the compiler and a simple text formatted with the `\tt` font will be rendered instead.

You can find a "live" example here: https://github.com/madrisan/cv

Comment: the links in your CV are not clickable when opening the file in github (https://github.com/madrisan/cv/blob/master/dmadrisan_cv_en.pdf), shame on github :p

Comment: could you explain roughly what your code does?

Comment: It injects some postscript code that make the parameter #1 of the macro `\url` a clickable URL. I forgot to say that a prefix `https://` is added. This should be not an issue nowadays. If you want to support `http://` links you can easily modify the macro.